# Type different between .GetType() and Get-Member

Tags: powershell

Why does GetType() not return the same type as Get-Member?

```
PS C:\> Find-Module -Name vssetup | Install-Module
PS C:\> $x = (Get-VSSetupInstance)[0]
PS C:\> $x.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    Instance                                 System.Object

PS C:\> $x | Get-Member

   TypeName: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Instance

Name                MemberType Definition
----                ---------- ----------
Equals              Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode         Method     int GetHashCode()
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type being reported *is* the same, it's just *its representation* that differs.

As of PowerShell 7.3.4, the *for-display* formatting of the [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo) instance returned by `.GetType()` - unfortunately - doesn't reflect the type's *namespace-qualified* name, whereas [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Member)'s output does.

To get the type's namespace-qualified name based on a `.GetType()` call, simply access the returned object's `.FullName` property:

```bash
# -> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Instance'
$x.GetType().FullName
```

Note that `Get-Member`'s purpose is not *only* to report a .NET type's *identity*, but also to report *its members* - hence the additional information about `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, ... (mediated via the for-display formatting of the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition) instances that `Get-Member` outputs).

As such, the details of the for-display formatting are *by design* different.

---

As an aside:

- Unfortunately, `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition` instance, while providing useful, nicely formatted *high-level* information about .NET type members, they do *not* provide access to the *full .NET reflection APIs* that the [`System.Reflection.MemberInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.MemberInfo)-derived instances output by the reflection methods called directly on types ( `.GetType().GetMember(...)`, etc.) do.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76884750/45375) for function `Get-NativeMember`, which offers similar convenience to `Get-Member`, but returns the actual `System.Reflection.MemberInfo`-derived instances for full access to .NET's reflection API; note that it does so for type-*native* members only (not also for members provided via PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System)).