# powershell Get-Member (MemberDefinition) to .Net MemberInfo

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

How to transition from PowerShell reflection to .Net reflection?

If I have `MemberDefinition` for a `Method` (i.e. `'' | gm -Name Insert`), how can get it attributes?

Comment: There's not necessarily a 1-to-1 mapping - `Get-Member` also shows non-.NET members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MemberDefinition` is just a POCO with 4 data members, so nothing fancy can be done here: just use those string properties to resolve type/member.

```
filter Resolve-NetType {
    [OutputType([System.Reflection.MemberInfo])] param()
    ([type]$_.TypeName).GetMember($_.Name)
}
```

```
'' | gm -Name ToString |
    Resolve-NetType |
    % { "$($_.GetType().Name) $($_.Name)($($_.GetParameters() | % { $_.CustomAttributes + $_.ParameterType + $_.Name}))" }

# RuntimeMethodInfo ToString()
# RuntimeMethodInfo ToString([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute((Byte)2)] System.IFormatProvider provider)
```

@mklement0 suggested to use `PSMethod` (late bound delegate in terms of C#), but it's actually more tricky to do anything with it beside `Invoke`, since there is no direct access to original type, but we can workaround it via reflection.

```
$bindingFlagsAll=[System.Reflection.bindingflags]'IgnoreCase,Instance,Static,NonPublic,Public'

function Get-Target {
    [OutputType([object])] param([System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo]$PSMember)
    [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo].GetField('instance', $bindingFlagsAll).GetValue($PSMember)
}
```

So combined:

```
filter Resolve-NetType {
    [OutputType([System.Reflection.MemberInfo])] param()
    # TODO: check $_.MemberType to filter out ETS members
    if ($_ -is [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition])
    { ([type]$_.TypeName).GetMember($_.Name) }
    else
    { (Get-Target $_).GetType().GetMember($_.Name) }
}

(''.Chars, ($true | gm -Name ToString)) |
    Resolve-NetType |
    % { "$($_.GetType().Name) $($_.CustomAttributes) $($_.Name)" }

# RuntimePropertyInfo  Chars
# RuntimeMethodInfo [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute((Byte)1)] ToString
# RuntimeMethodInfo [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute((Byte)1)] ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler alternative to [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) for ***method* members**, specifically, you can **access the method *without parentheses***, which **prints its overloads**:

```bash
# Note: NO parentheses
''.Insert
```

Output:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string Insert(int startIndex, string value)
```

This is not only simpler but also faster than `Get-Member`, and has the added advantage of printing each overload *on its own line*; e.g.:

```bash
(Get-Date).ToString
```

Output:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string ToString()
string ToString(string format)
string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider)
string IFormattable.ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider formatProvider)
string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)
```

**Caveat**:

- The display output is the based on the value of the `.OverloadDefinitions` property of the [`System.Management.Automation.PSMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSMethod) instance that accessing a method without parentheses emits.
- This property contains a **collection of *strings*, each describing a method overload**; that is, no further programmatic exploration of such overloads is possible; they're **primarily useful for *visual* inspection**.

---

In order to **get *additional* information about members** - such as **custom attributes** - you can **use .NET's reflection method directly**:

Call [`.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Object.GetType) on any given (non-null) .NET object, which returns a [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo), which is a rich source of reflection.

```bash
# Get all overloads of the .ToString() method of type [datetime]
(Get-Date).GetType().GetMembers() | Where-Object Name -eq 'ToString'
```

Alternatively, directly via the *type*, using a type literal:

```bash
# Get all overloads of the .ToString() method of type [string]
[datetime].GetMembers() | Where-Object Name -eq 'ToString'
```

The output will be quite verbose, but you do get access to the full object model of the [`System.Reflection.MemberInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.MemberInfo)-derived instances, such as instances [`System.Reflection.MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.MethodInfo).

---

##### Convenience function `Get-NativeMember`:

`Get-NativeMember` (source code below) is meant to provide helpful display formatting without sacrificing access access to information, which is what [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) unfortunately does. `Get-NativeMember` works similarly to `Get-Member`, but with some crucial differences:

- It operates on *type-native* .NET members only, not also on PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System) members.
- It outputs [`System.Reflection.MemberInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.MemberInfo)-derived instances, which provide full access to the .NET reflection APIs.
- However, similar to `Get-Member`, for *display formatting* it presents a friendlier, condensed view, albeit with more information than `Get-Member`, notably including attributes and custom attributes, if present.
- Unlike `Get-Member`:

  - It supports `-Type Constructor` to show constructor definitions too.
- You can pass *types* as input (e.g. `[string] | Get-NativeMember -Type Property` works the same as `'foo' | Get-NativeMember -Type Property`
- Static members are included by default (but labeled as such); you can use `-BindingFlags Instance` / `-BindingFlags Static` to get *only* instance members / static members.

Limitations (all of which could be addressed with more effort):

- Parameterized properties are treated like other properties; it is the presence of `[<typename>[,...]]` after the property name that implies a parameterized property (e.g., `Char Chars [Int32]`)
- Only a custom *list* view is defined and used by default; piping to `| Format-Table` results in unhelpful display.

**Example:**

```bash
# Get reflection info about the .Chars (parameterized) property
# and the .ToString() method overloads.
'' | Get-NativeMember Chars, ToString
```

Output:

```bash
   Name: Chars - System.String

MemberType                : Property
Definition                : Char Chars [Int32] { get; }


   Name: ToString - System.String

MemberType                : Method
Definition                : System.String ToString(
                            )
Attributes                : Public, Virtual, HideBySig

MemberType                : Method
Definition                : System.String ToString(
                              System.IFormatProvider provider
                            )
Attributes                : Public, Final, Virtual, HideBySig, VtableLayoutMask
ParameterCustomAttributes : [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableAttribute((Byte)2)]
```

For *methods* and *parameterized properties*, you may also use the `PSMemberInfo` instances that PowerShell outputs when you don't make an actual call with `()` or return an actual element with `[]` - thanks to techniques borrowed [from your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76896417/45375):

```bash
''.Chars, $true.ToString | Get-NativeMember
```

Note that this does *not* work with other member types: regular properties invariably *return their value* when accessed (e.g. `'foo'.Length`) and other member types aren't directly available with dot notation (e.g. constructors and events) - for those you'll have to use `-MemberType`, possibly combined with `-Name`.

**`Get-NativeMember` source code:**

```bash
function Get-NativeMember {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false, DefaultParameterSetName = 'PSMemberInfo')]
  param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Native', Position = 0)]
    [SupportsWildcards()] [string[]]
    $Name
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Native', Position = 1, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] 
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [ValidateScript({ if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo]) { throw '[System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo] input cannot be combined with -Name, -MemberType, or -BindingFlags.' }; $true })]
    [object] $InputObject
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PSMemberInfo', Position = 1, Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo] $PSMemberInfo
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Native')]
    [Alias('Type')]
    [System.Reflection.MemberTypes] $MemberType
    ,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Native')]
    [Reflection.BindingFlags] $BindingFlags = 'Instance, Static, Public'
    ,
    [switch] $Force
  )
    
  begin {
    Set-StrictMode -Version 1
    # Make sure that at least either Instance or Static and Public or Non-Public are present.
    if (-not ($BindingFlags -band 'Public, NonPublic')) { $BindingFlags = $BindingFlags -bor 'Public' }
    if (-not ($BindingFlags -band 'Instance, Static')) { $BindingFlags = $BindingFlags -bor 'Instance, Static' }
    Write-Verbose "Binding flags: $BindingFlags"
    
    # Create the formatting data on demand.
    # Set $env:__GNM_DEBUG = 1 for debugging, to ensure that the formatting data is reloaded every time.
    if (-not (Get-FormatData -ErrorAction Ignore NativeMemberDetails) -or $env:__GNM_DEBUG) {
      Write-Verbose 'Creating formatting data for this session.'
      # Create a temporary file with formatting definitions to pass to 
      # Update-FormatData below.
      $tempFile = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) 'NativeMemberDetails.Format.ps1xml'
        
      @'
    <Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
      <View>
        <Name>NativeMemberDetails</Name>
        <ViewSelectedBy>
          <TypeName>NativeMemberDetails</TypeName>
        </ViewSelectedBy>
        <GroupBy>
          <Label>Name</Label>
          <ScriptBlock>('{0}{1} - {2}' -f $_.Name, ('', ' (static)')[([bool] $_.IsStatic -or ($_.MemberType -eq 'Property' -and $_.GetMethod.IsStatic))], $_.DeclaringType.FullName) -replace '^\.c?ctor', 'Constructors'</ScriptBlock>
        </GroupBy>
        <ListControl>
          <ListEntries>
            <ListEntry>
              <ListItems>
                <ListItem><Label>MemberType               </Label><PropertyName>MemberType</PropertyName></ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <Label>Definition</Label>
                  <ScriptBlock><![CDATA[
                      # Use .NET's overload-specific stringification, which lacks parameter names, however - they are added below.
                      $signature = $_.ToString()
                      if ($_.MemberType -eq 'Event') {
                        # To discover the full event-delegate signature, more work is needed.
                        $paramList = $_.EventHandlerType.GetMethod('Invoke').GetParameters().ForEach({ '{0} {1}' -f $_.ParameterType.FullName, $_.Name }) -join ', '
                        "{0}(`n{1}`n)" -f $signature, ('  ' + (($paramList -split ', ') -join ",`n  "))
                      } elseif ($_.MemberType -eq 'Property') {
                        $isStatic = $_.GetMethod.IsStatic
                        $isPublic = $_.GetAccessors().Count -gt 0 # .GetAccessor() returns only public accessors by default.
                        '{0}{1}{2}' -f ('(non-public) ', '')[$isPublic], ('', 'static ')[$isStatic], $signature  + ('', (' {{ {0} }}' -f (('', 'get;')[$_.CanRead], ('', 'set;')[$_.CanWrite] -join ' ').Trim()))[$_.MemberType -eq 'Property']
                      }
                      else {
                        $returnTypeAndName, $paramList, $null = $signature -split '[()]'
                        $(
                          if (-not $paramList) { # Parameter-less methods and properties, including parameterized ones.
                            '{0}{1}' -f ('', 'static ')[$_.IsStatic], ($signature -replace '\(', "(`n")
                          } else {
                            [array] $paramNames = $_.GetParameters().Name; $i = 0
                            if (-not $paramNames) { $paramNames = 'value' }
                            "{0}{1}(`n{2}`n)" -f ('', 'static ')[$_.IsStatic], $returnTypeAndName, ('  ' + (($paramList -split ', ').ForEach({ '{0} {1}' -f $_, $paramNames[$i++]}) -join ",`n  "))
                          }
                        ) -replace '^Void .ctor', ('new ' + $_.DeclaringType.Name) # Note: We don't bother with static constructors; their signature is 'Void .cctor()'
                      }
                ]]></ScriptBlock>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <ItemSelectionCondition><PropertyName>Attributes</PropertyName></ItemSelectionCondition>
                  <PropertyName>Attributes</PropertyName>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <ItemSelectionCondition><PropertyName>CustomAttributes</PropertyName></ItemSelectionCondition>
                  <PropertyName>CustomAttributes</PropertyName>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <ItemSelectionCondition><ScriptBlock>$_.MemberType -eq 'Method' -and $_.GetParameters().Attributes.Where({ $_ -ne 'None'}).Count</ScriptBlock></ItemSelectionCondition>
                  <Label>ParameterAttributes</Label>
                  <ScriptBlock>$_.GetParameters().Attributes</ScriptBlock>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <ItemSelectionCondition><ScriptBlock>$_.MemberType -eq 'Method' -and $_.GetParameters().CustomAttributes</ScriptBlock></ItemSelectionCondition>
                  <Label>ParameterCustomAttributes</Label>
                  <ScriptBlock>$_.GetParameters().CustomAttributes</ScriptBlock>
                </ListItem>
              </ListItems>
            </ListEntry>
          </ListEntries>
        </ListControl>
      </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
    </Configuration>
'@ > $tempFile
    
      # Load the formatting data into the current session.
      Update-FormatData -AppendPath $tempFile
    
      # Clean up.
      Remove-Item -LiteralPath $tempFile
    
    }
  }
    
  process {
    if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'PSMemberInfo') {
      # Using reflection on a private field, obtain the object instance that the member-info instance pertains to.
      $InputObject = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo].GetField('instance', 'Instance, NonPublic, Public').GetValue($PSMemberInfo)
      $Name = $PSMemberInfo.Name
    }
    # If the input object is a type definition, query it directly, else obtain the input object's type,
    # (except if a PSMemberInfo with a [type] member was passed).
    $inputIsType = $InputObject -is [Type]
    $typeDef = if ($inputIsType -and $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Native') { $InputObject } else { $InputObject.GetType() }
    & {
      if ($Name) { 
        foreach ($n in $Name) {
          if ($MemberType) {
            $typeDef.GetMember($n, $MemberType, $BindingFlags)
          }
          else {
            $typeDef.GetMember($n, $BindingFlags)
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        $typeDef.GetMembers($BindingFlags) | 
          Where-Object { -not $MemberType -or $MemberType.HasFlag($_.MemberType) }
        }
      } |
        Where-Object {
          $Force -or $_.MemberType -eq 'Constructor' -or -not $_.IsSpecialName
        } |
        ForEach-Object {
          # Make sure that each output object has the ETS type name that triggers
          # formatting via the custom format definitions.
          if ('NativeMemberDetails' -notin $_.PSTypeNames) { $_.PSTypeNames.Insert(0, 'NativeMemberDetails') }
          $_
        }
  }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks(+1) for response, but I was looking for actual reflection (i.e. parameters types and attributes not in string format).

Comment: I use this in interactive console for exploration. Firstly I pipe through `Get-Member -....` (which handles edge cases gracefully, i.e. non-homogeneous collections) to see if property is not coming from ETS. Then if I need more info dropping to manual use of native reflection requires amending cmdline (inserting `(...)` and `[0]`, etc). See my answer. Thanks again for handy method for adding data formatter and formatter itself, I will definitely add it to my profile.

Comment: I think you should move `foreach ($n in $names)` loop inside `Where-Object` to reflect only once per object. Also `IsTypeDefinition` will break with generics, I think you meant `-is [type]`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed feedback, @OwnageIsMagic, and I'm gad to hear the formatter code is helpful. I've fixed the `.IsTypeDefinition` problem, and have modified the name-filtering code. I have amended the function to directly accept `PSMemberInfo` as input, which now borrows from your answer. Thus, you can now do `''.Chars, $true.ToString | Get-NativeMember`, for instance, but for members that aren't methods or parameterized properties you'll again need to use `Get-NativeMember`'s parameters.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic, note that there's a number of open issues for `Get-Member` in the `GitHub` repo: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+get-member It may be worth opening a feature request: to have `System.Reflection.MemberInfo` instances 
 added as a _property_ to the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition` instances output by `Get-Member`.